# Can we send data from Kinesis Data Streams to Kinesis Analytics and Firehose simultaneously without loss of data

Tags: amazon-kinesis

For example: If I have 1000 records in Data stream, I want to send it to Kinesis Analytics and Kinesis Firehose simultaneously i.e. Both Kinesis Analytics and Firehose should get 1000 records each. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can configure Kinesis analytics with your kinesis stream as a source.

In the same way, you can configure firehose with the kinesis stream.

Both services will behave as 2 different consumers.